# Why does the typescript aws-cdk init-template include its app in the bin directory and as a binary in package.json?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

In the [aws-cdk init-template for typescript](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/master/packages/aws-cdk/lib/init-templates/v2/app/typescript), the template creates content [in the bin directory](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/aws-cdk/lib/init-templates/v2/app/typescript/bin/%25name%25.template.ts) and links it [to the bin property](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/aws-cdk/lib/init-templates/v2/app/typescript/package.template.json#L5) of package.json.

I'd like to understand why.

I'm confused because the bin directory content has the default cdk app for the project, but it doesn't seem like an executable file on its own since it would usually be used inside the context of a cdk command like the one in the [template's cdk.json](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/aws-cdk/lib/init-templates/v2/app/typescript/cdk.template.json#L2)

Is there a use case for [node's symlinking behavior that I'm not seeing](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#bin)?

[edit: clarifying]

This isn't causing an issue other than my understanding of the intent and whether there is some use case inside the aws-cdk tooling for having the bin symlinking behavior (so I don't break that use case while modifying the project).

Comment: i didn't understand the exact issue that it is causing and I don't know the reason behind why they do that. But we can easily dump the lib and bin folders and have a regular src folder with index.js as standard NodeJs, I always do that at the start of the new project.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is meant to signal to the developer the intent of the files.

The CDK App is what you execute to provision on environment, so it goes into the bin.

The lib contains a library of stacks/components that are used by the App.